# setTimeout within for loop doesn't return expected result

Tags: javascript, for-loop, data-structures, settimeout

My code is

```
for(let i =0; i<10; i++) {
  const timer = (i*1000);
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i, timer), timer)
}
```

**My code returns each log only 1s apart from previous. But, expected is

- when i=1, print after 1s;
- at i=2 print after 2s;
- at i=3, print after 3s

**

Comment: you are describing the same thing twice:
"each log only 1s apart from previous"
is the same as
"when i=1, print after 1s;
at i=2 print after 2s;
at i=3, print after 3s"
do you really want to start the second timer after the first completed?

Answer (score 3):

You can keep track of the timeout time that was last set and add to it each iteration:

```js
let timer = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  timer += i * 1000;
  const thisTimer = timer;
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i, thisTimer), timer)
}
```

A more readable option would be to `await` the resolution of the timeout:

```js
(async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const timer = i * 1000;
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timer));
    console.log(i, timer);
  }
})();
```

Your current code doesn't work because the `timeout` being passed to `setTimeout` is only being incremented by 1000 each time, so every callback runs 1000 ms apart, rather than 1000 then 2000 then 3000, etc. apart.

Answer (score 0):

`SetTimeOut()` does not stop the code from running. You basically set 3 timeouts at the same time with 1s, 2s, and 3s so each goes off 1s apart from previous.

If you want execute `console.log` after each other with time delay you can use a recursive function:

```
function timerLog(start, end) {
    const timer = (start * 1000);
    if (start == end + 1) {
        return;
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(start, timer);
        timerLog(start + 1, end);
    }, timer);
}
//
timerLog(1, 3);
```